# Formula to search array and return values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a Quotation Book and an Order Book each with a column called Q#. In the Quotation Book the quote numbers are generated and in the Order Book quote numbers are entered without being in order.

When the Quotation becomes an Order and needs an order number, I need help with a formula to take a number from the Quotation Book column Q# (eg `A3`) and search for that number in the entirety of the Q# column in the Order Book.  The return in a separate column should be TRUE if found and otherwise FALSE.

What formula should I use?

Comment: Did you try a Vlookup?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done not just for a single instance chosen from Quotation but for all, with one formula (in `B3` in example) copied down as required:

[image: SU589142 example]

The basis is that, for `A3`: if `A3` is found in Order the result will be `TRUE`, otherwise the absence will give rise to an error that is then displayed as `FALSE`.

Comment: just 1 more thing, what if my Order Q# column has more then 1 number in it and i want it to pick up both